# How to overwrite a jQuery function or stop it from executing

Tags: jquery, function, execution

I have a jQuery function that transforms a WordPress menu into a floating menu and then back again.

I would like to create a demonstration panel in the theme that allows users to toggle or switch between the static and floating menu.

The working site can be seen here: http://morphius.wpinsite.com

Here is the jQuery Code that sets the menu to floating.

```
function header_transform(){

        window_y = $(window).scrollTop();
        var wp_admin_height = "0px";
        if ($("#wpadminbar").length > 0){
            wp_admin_height = parseInt($("#wpadminbar").height()) + "px";
        }
        if (window_y > scroll_critical) {
            if (!($("#header-wrapper").hasClass("fixed"))){
                    $("#header-wrapper").hide();
                    $("#wrapper").css("margin-top", header_h + "px");
                    $("#header-wrapper").addClass("fixed").css("top", wp_admin_height);
                    $("#header-wrapper").fadeIn(500);
                    //$logo2_link.fadeIn().appendTo(".header");
                    $logo2_link.fadeIn().prependTo(".header");
                    fixedmenu = true;
            }


        } else {
            if (($("#header-wrapper").hasClass("fixed"))){
                $("#header-wrapper").fadeOut(500, function(){
                    $("#header-wrapper").removeClass("fixed");
                    $("#wrapper").css("margin-top", "");
                    $("#header-wrapper").fadeIn(300)
                });

                $logo2_link.fadeOut().remove();
                fixedmenu = false;
            }

        }
}
```

What I want to achieve is that if the user clicks on the demo options panel and sets the menu to "fixed" then the below jQuery code will not execute and transform the menu.

By default the below jQuery code will always run. I just need a way to stop it from executing if someone clicks the "Fixed" menu option.

Thanks

Comment: You can use `.off()` or `.unbind()` to remove an event handler (they're the opposites of `.on()` and `.bind()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the beginning of your function add sth like this:

```
if($(".switcherFixed img").hasClass("selected")) {
    return;
}
```

Did it help?

Comment: Hi Carlos, yes worked great, thank you. Just need to add a little extra jQuery code to hide the logo.

Comment: No worries - everything is easier with jQuery!